# Difference between throw and return in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can you tell me the difference between `return` and `throw` in Dart and where to use them?

Comment: Have you considered consullting the documentation?

Answer (score 4):

Functions in dart can return a value, for that you use the return word;

```dart
String convertIntToString(int value){
  return value.toString();
  //After return everything else is ignored
}
```

```dart
String result = convertIntToString(2);
```

The throw word it is used to throw an error when something is not as expected.

```dart
String convertIntToString(int value){
  if(value != null) throw("value should not be null");
  //If a throw is called the function stops there and ignore the rest
  return value.toString();
}
```

With try an catch you handle the error

```dart
try {
  String result = convertIntToString(null);
} catch(e) {
  print(e)
}
```

See more about error handling at https://medium.com/run-dart/dart-dartlang-introduction-exception-handling-f9f088906f7c